# Mantine DateInput arrow formatting problems

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, mantine

The mantine DateInput formatting is off. The arrows are too large, and it looks like there might be a second column.

I created a basic react app and only added @mantine/core and @mantine/dates version 7.5.0 using the command `npx create-react-app my-app`. Then I changed the App.js file:

```
import {DateInput} from "@mantine/dates";
import {createTheme, MantineProvider} from "@mantine/core";

function App() {
  return (
          <MantineProvider theme={createTheme({})}>
              <DateInput
                  label={'Set Start Date'}
                  placeholder={'date here'}
              />
          </MantineProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When I run `npm run start`, I see this in my chrome browser (Version 120.0.6099.109 (Official Build) (x86_64)):

Badly formatted Mantine DateInput:

[image: Badly formatted Mantine DateInput]

Is there a bug with this mantine version? If not, how do I fix the formatting so that the DateInput looks like the DateInput in the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that you have to import the @mantine/dates css:

`import '@mantine/dates/styles.css'`

make sure to import any `@matine` styles in correct order, according to [docs](https://mantine.dev/styles/mantine-styles/#styles-import-order):

> It is important to keep the correct styles import order. @mantine/core
> package styles must always be imported before any other Mantine
> package styles:
>
> ```
> // ✅ Correct order 
> import '@mantine/core/styles.css'; 
> import '@mantine/dates/styles.css'; 
>
> // ❌ Incorrect order 
> import '@mantine/dates/styles.css'; 
> import '@mantine/core/styles.css';
> ```
>
> Your application styles must always be imported after all @mantine/*
> packages styles:
>
> ```
> // ✅ Correct order - your styles will override Mantine styles
> import '@mantine/core/styles.css'; 
> import '@mantine/dates/styles.css';
> import classes from './Demo.module.css';
>
> // ❌ Incorrect order – Mantine styles will override your styles 
> import classes from './Demo.module.css'; 
> import '@mantine/core/styles.css';
> import '@mantine/dates/styles.css';
> ```